# Fortran: list of matrices as a function argument

Tags: list, matrix, data-structures, fortran, fortran90

I need to implement an algorithm that operates on a list of matrices. The number of matrices and their sizes are not known in advance - a user is free to apply the algorithm to any finite number of matrices of any size. How can I implement such behavior in Fortran code? Is there a proper data structure available to do that? I am looking for a well-established Fortran programming pattern.

It is relatively easy to implement such an algorithm in Python using a combination of the *list* data structure and *numpy* matrices, but it works way to slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note I have assumed that all your matrices have elements of the same data type.

Here is a simplified (and through that very slightly old fashioned) example of what I would do

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat list_of_matrices.f90 
Module numbers_module

  Implicit None

  Integer, Parameter, Public :: wp = Selected_real_kind( 12, 70 )

  Private

End Module numbers_module

Module matrix_module

  Use numbers_module, Only : wp

  Implicit None

  Type, Public :: matrix
     Real( wp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable, Public :: data
  End type matrix

  Public :: matrix_allocate
  Public :: matrix_free
  Public :: matrix_set_with_random
  Public :: matrix_print

  Private

Contains

  Subroutine matrix_allocate( A, m, n )

    Type( matrix ), Intent(   Out ) :: A
    Integer       , Intent( In    ) :: m
    Integer       , Intent( In    ) :: n

    Allocate( A%data( 1:m, 1:n ) )

  End Subroutine matrix_allocate

  Subroutine matrix_free( A )

    Type( matrix ), Intent( InOut ) :: A

    Deallocate( A%data )

  End Subroutine matrix_free

  Subroutine matrix_set_with_random( A )

    Type( matrix ), Intent( InOut ) :: A

    Call Random_number( A%data )

  End Subroutine matrix_set_with_random

  Subroutine matrix_print( A, format )

    Type( matrix )      , Intent( In ) :: A
    Character( Len = * ), Intent( In ) :: format

    Integer :: i

    Write( *, * ) 'The matrix has the shape: ', Shape( A%data )
    Do i = 1, Size( A%data, Dim = 1 )
       Write( *, format ) A%data( i, : )
    End Do

  End Subroutine matrix_print

End Module matrix_module

Program test_matrix

  Use matrix_module, Only : matrix, matrix_allocate, matrix_free, &
       matrix_set_with_random, matrix_print

  Implicit None

  Type( matrix ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: list_of_matrices

  Integer :: n_mats
  Integer :: n, m
  Integer :: i_mat

  Write( *, * ) 'How many matrices'
  Read ( *, * ) n_mats

  Allocate( list_of_matrices( 1:n_mats ) )

  Do i_mat = 1, n_mats
     Write( *, * ) 'Dimensions for matrix ', i_mat
     Read ( *, * ) m, n
     Call matrix_allocate( list_of_matrices( i_mat ), m, n )
     Call matrix_set_with_random( list_of_matrices( i_mat ) )
  End Do

  Do i_mat = 1, n_mats
     Write( *, * ) 'Data for matrix ', i_mat
     Call matrix_print( list_of_matrices( i_mat ), '( 20( f5.2, 1x ) )' )
  End Do

  Do i_mat = n_mats, 1, -1
     Call matrix_free( list_of_matrices( i_mat ) )
  End Do
  Deallocate( list_of_matrices )

End Program test_matrix
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -Wuse-without-only -Wsurprising -Wimplicit-interface -Werror -fcheck=all list_of_matrices.f90 -o list_of_matrices
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./list_of_matrices 
 How many matrices
3
 Dimensions for matrix            1
2 1
 Dimensions for matrix            2
4 3
 Dimensions for matrix            3
5 6
 Data for matrix            1
 The matrix has the shape:            2           1
 0.06
 0.31
 Data for matrix            2
 The matrix has the shape:            4           3
 0.02  0.63  0.08
 0.26  0.84  0.75
 0.85  0.67  0.34
 0.85  0.91  0.33
 Data for matrix            3
 The matrix has the shape:            5           6
 0.35  0.58  0.01  0.93  0.74  0.46
 0.43  0.38  0.89  0.83  0.51  0.26
 0.33  0.03  0.73  0.26  0.40  0.58
 0.48  0.87  0.15  0.62  0.13  0.79
 0.59  0.97  0.15  0.09  0.05  0.37
ian@eris:~/work/stack$
```

In practice I would have the contents of the derived type kept private and only accessible by the module procedures, and nowadays I would use type bound procedures within the matrix type, but for this I think that distracts from the point hence going the slightly older route. In production code I would also probably have a separate list_of_matrices type to hold the array of matrices, but it depends on exactly what you are doing.

In fact I am currently working on something which is essentially a much more complicated version of this - routines to perform linear algebra on list of matrices, where those matrices may be either real or complex, and the data within those matrices can be distributed across multiple processes. Having just berated somebody for asking us to download unknown files I feel somewhat guilty about this, but if interested you can find it on github:

```
git clone https://github.com/drijbush/dmat2.git
```